Dynamically build a JSON Object while omitting null or undefined optional fields
I feel there must be a simple solution to this but for the life of me cannot find it! I have a model which has optional fields like so:
export interface myCompany {
    name: string,
    type: string,
    postal: number,
    hasOffice: boolean,
    officeCode?: string,
}

In this example, officeCode is an optional field and only applicable when hasOffice is true. When building a payload, I'm iterating through an array of myCompany objects and building this JSON for each one. Something like..
companyArray.forEach((myCompany) => {
     payload.push({
         name: myCompany.name,
         type: myCompany.type,
         postal: myCompany.postal,
         hasOffice: myCompany.hasOffice,
         officeCode: myCompany.officeCode ? myCompany.officeCode : null,
     });
});

The problem is my payload now contains objects which have officeCode: null in the payload, when I would rather omit the field entirely. This is a simple example in which one could just have two payloads, one for each case, but I'm facing payloads where I have dozens of optional fields.
Is there a simple way to tell Typescript to omit officeCode entirely if it finds that it is undefined or null?
My backup plan is to go through each payload before post and remove any null fields with a utility function. I think this is possible but also not ideal.

Yes, sorry, I will fix that.

Use undefined instead of null, it'll be stripped out by JSON.stringify when you send the object as a JSON payload:
const payload = companyArray.map(myCompany => ({
    name: myCompany.name,
    type: myCompany.type,
    postal: myCompany.postal,
    hasOffice: myCompany.hasOffice,
    officeCode: myCompany.officeCode || undefined,
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^
}));

If you want to omit only null and undefined values, not everything falsy (like an empty string), use ?? instead of ||.

Thank you so much for this! I didn't realize JSON.stringify would strip those out on POST since I log everything before POSTing, and the log still showed them as present but having a value of undefined. This does work though! Appreciate it!

const payload = companyArray.map(({ name, type, postal, hasOffice, officeCode }) => ({
    name,
    type,
    postal,
    hasOffice,
    ...(hasOffice && officeCode ? { officeCode } : {})
}));

